# CSS: how to define position of child div inside parent div with multiple divs

Tags: html, css, position, parent

What I have - parent `div` with several (5) child `divs`. And few child `divs` contain text, hence they may change their side and move others inside parent `div` (in certain volume).

But I need that **4th** of child `div` stays at his place all the time (see picture attached).[image]

I tried to define its position using `position:relative` for parent and `position:absolute` for needed `div` (let's call him - "Object"). But in this situation when the height of other child `divs`, locating higher than Object, changes, one of them may stay on the content of the "Object" (over it).

Moreover, I found that with `position:absolute` "Object" started to ignore padding of parent `div`!

As I see - I need to fix somehow the position of Object in relation with top border of parent div. BUT - margin-top for 4th div doesn't work for it, as it moves the child div #3 above.

I am new to CSS and will be glad if anyone may help me.

```
// doesn't work as needed:
div#father {position: relative;} 
div#son5 {position: absolute;}
```

initial draft code for parent and child divs at Jfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/741rzafq/2/

Comment: can you add a desired layout (rough)?

Comment: Perhaps you could create a JSFiddle (or something similar)? It would make it much easier to understand your goal.

Comment: add you desired design as a drawing. Add your code as a minimal reproduciable code snippet. A very vague css code line does not help to understand the situation nor what you trying to do.

Comment: thank you for your comments!! I added both jsfiddle and png of needed situation.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep the element fixed at its position, you can use position:fixed; for that element. It will remain at its position even if you scroll the page.

Comment: its vague and unclear what the OP is actually trying to do. Such comments should be givin as a comment not as an anwser.

Comment: @tacoshy, new users cannot make comments. The only way is to answer like Ayush did.